# System shuts down abruptly

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, shutdown

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed in my system. My system shuts down randomly from last 2 months.

I gave it to the service centre as it was within warranty. They replaced many components like **motherboard, CPU, PSU** but this problem still comes time and again. The problem is quite random and it is arising every week since last 2 weeks. Rest of the days it works fine.

Earlier(before handing it over to service centre), it used to happen every 2 to 3 days.

This problem of freezing appeared in Windows and even in BIOS too. So it seems that the problem is not software related.

**SPECS are**

```
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600
Motheboard: MSI A320M PRO-VD/S
RAM: 8 GB 2400MHz DDR 4 Corsair
SSD: 120GB SSD Kingston
HDD: 1 TB HDD Seagate
PSU: PSU MWE 450 watts
Graphics: INNO3D GEFORCE GT 710 2GB DDR3 LP
```

PFA the files [kern.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kfOWwguPmqFceLye20PY3gpHyMsM8RFz), [syslog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19XjY0HH_Oi_kvyeNXwU_5t_o2pQwVnsR) and [systemstats](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BcN_31iVrliIXJ3ZXeXS5oadwyB73FGP) that I generated.

Here are the timelines for crash as per log file

1. After 4:30 PM 31st August and before 5:13 PM 31st August
2. Around 6:38 PM 31st August
3. Around 8:24 PM 31st August

Any help to figure out/pinpoint the problem is appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect an electrical issue here. Can you try connecting the system to a different power supply (e.g. in the basement of a friend's) or plug it into a UPS of some sort?

Or, if already under UPS, try a different UPS or no UPS at all?

Comment: This problem also occurred when I took it to service centre..

Also the problem is random.. Sometimes it occurs in a week, sometimes in an hour.. So there is nothing fixed about the problem..

Even people from service centre are confused why this keeps happening

Comment: I assume they checked the power and reset buttons too? Seeing as both psu and mb were replaced... what if you disconnect those from the mb?

Comment: Didn't get you!! What exactly to disconnect?

Comment: @rock321987 sorry! I meant the reset and power buttons. This is the only thing I can think of that might be connected with board power, and yet remain unchanged when replacing both PSU and motherboard. Unless it's a frayed power cable (happened to me once), but I guess the shop would have used its own.

Comment: Basically  what happens is that the system doesn't shut down. Display goes off, mouse and keyboard are disconnected. LED near RAM starts glowing and I have to press the reboot button to restart the PC